# Deploy disk image made with macrium to VMWare

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, vmware-workstation, deployment, macrium

I beg for everyone patients, I'm new to computers.

I backed up a desktop using macrium to a disk image.

I want to deploy this image to vmware 15.5 for workstations on my windows 10 pro workstation.

Needless to say, macrium is not a format that can be deployed to VMware.

I tried mounting the image to a volume on the PC but i don't know how to write that volume to an iso.

All the imaging tools i have on my machine (and i have many) would either output and .img or throw an eror : "file is to big".

Can someone recommend the right tool or a correct way to deploy a disk image made with Macrium to VMWare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need for the following a version of VMWare Workstation, as I'm not sure that
you can do it with VMware Player.

- Create a bootable
  [Macrium Rescue Media](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Creating+rescue+media)
  of ISO format
- Use VMWare to create a virtual machine of the same type, without installing
  an operating system (yet)
- Set the Rescue ISO as the DVD drive of the VM
- You will need to assure that the VM can see the backup
- Boot the VM into Macrium and restore the backup.

Note that missing drivers might cause problems.
Your first action if the VM boots successfully should be to install
VMWare Tools.